# XCode 4.3 Command Line Tools Package with Invalid Checksum

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.3

The package Apple provides to install the command line tools with Xcode 4.3 is corrupted, and I seem to need it because I'm developing some command line tools.

Has anybody found an alternative Command Line package for Xcode 4.3 from Apple that works or an workaround for the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found a way to do this correctly.
The problem is really in one of the European mirrors from Apple.

The workaround is to:
- Install Tor: https://www.torproject.org/
- Choose a Tor node in the USA
- Logging into your Apple Developer account and download the package

It now opens correctly without any checksum warning.

Comment: I almost always have this problem (I'm in europe).
I then download the packages via https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Answer (score 8):

Xcode includes a new "Downloads" preference pane to install optional components such as command line tools, and previous iOS Simulators.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried that one also with the same result: Invalid Checksum. Did you manage to install correctly yourself?

Comment: Yes, no problem. But I did have to download Xcode twice, the first time there was a checksum error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem of downloading/installing Xcode 4.3.1 "Command Line Tools" by getting them directly from the developer's webpage.  The March version yielded a checksum error just like
the download from within Xcode 4.3.1, i.e. Xcode/Preferences/Downloads .  But I did have success with the February version of CLT.  I don't know why things were out-of-sync.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to install the Command Line Tools from the Downloads tab in the XCode preferences (also downloading from Europe). I fixed it by clearing the dns cache on my system.

This is the Terminal command to clear the dns cache (OSX Lion):

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Restart XCode after running this command, it may not fix the problem with the checksum until you do.

Answer (score 1):

try:
defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify -bool true

Comment: Hi. I can skip error verification, but that's not my intention since I don't know if the checksum is incorrect due to incorrect package signing or due to package corruption at the Apple site.

I did find another user with the same problem. So, I'm guessing it might be a mirror problem (I'm in Europe) or a developer problem (I download from the Apple Safari Developer Page and the other user with the same problem as well).

Comment: I download Xcode and the Command Line tools many times, both from the Developer Page and from App Store and i got the same problem. So i used the command i said and now the Command Line Tools is installed. Btw, i'm in EU too.

Comment: Hi again. I managed to go around the problem and using Tor downloaded from the USA mirror and the package there is fine witouth any checksum error.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another mirror for the download site:

Use the following to determine a valid ip:
http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/dns-query.shtml?address=adcdownload.apple.com

and add this to /etc/hosts:

adcdownload.apple.com

Example (ip might already have changed)

64.211.144.168 adcdownload.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click skip while the disk image is verifying.  I have installed from a dmg of CLT-4.3 with this problem and built an extensive amount of software with if successfully on my te

Comment: If the disk image doesn't pass verification, you should assume that the contents are corrupted and not use them.