# MonoTouch: no gcc compiler found

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In the middle of MonoTouch/Xcode upgrade to fix broken app in app store. Can't seem to get everything to work again. Stuck right now in what looks like a broken configuration, as `mtouch` can't seem to find `gcc`.

`gcc` does seem available, and I can compile an sample iphone project on xcode

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such things can happen when:

a) Installing Xcode 4.3[.1] and when Xcode 4.2 is removed (the installer ask for this) or if it was never installed.

To fix this you need to install the optional "Command Line Tools" to get a complete installation.

You can do this from inside Xcode using those steps: [XCode 4.3 Command Line Tools Package with Invalid Checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9348718/220643)

b) when you install Xcode in a non-default directory. In this case you'll need to tell MonoDevelop where the Apple SDK is located. You can change this in the MonoDevelop's preferences dialog, SDK locations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I do have the command line tools optional package installed. Monodevelop also declares Apple SDK found at default location. Note that mtouch returns this error when run from command line too.

Comment: Also seeing this in a clean machine, which probably means I'm missing something and not that I got my other one in a bad state. For the command line tools, is there anything that needs to be done beyond installing on the preferences pane?

Comment: MonoTouch 5.0.2 is older than Xcode 4.3 so the new paths were not known at that time. You need to stay with Xcode 4.2 or update to the 5.2.5. See http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/17/update-on-xcode-4-3-support/

Comment: Yep, that was it. I ended buying an upgrade and after that things worked again. Not sure if it is possible to have older Xcode with new SDK (which I needed to target/test 5.1, as that's where I had the problem I was fixing) and avoid the upgrade, decided that eventually I would likely upgrade anyways, so why waste the time trying to figure out if it could been made to work. Would be great if that error message hinted at the possible causes of problem, although hopefully this post will help the next person running into it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @poupou Is there a way to manually specify the gcc location? I'm on latest Xcode (from App Store) but cannot upgrade to latest MonoTouch (support expired). The Apple SDK location is specified (with a green checkmark) but I'm still getting gcc not found.

Comment: No, you can downgrade Xcode to 4.2 (safest approach) or you can **try** creating a *symlink* with the `ln` command-line tool so the `gcc` (path + file names) being looked for can be found and mapped to the one provided by the new Xcode release. Note that you might have to do this for other tools as well.